# SQL COUNT in subquery

Tags: sql, count

I have a table orders(id, customer, service_area)

I need to find the count of customers that have placed more than 2 orders in service_area and display count of the customers that have done it. I have found out that this shows the number of customers that have more then x orders.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(id)) FROM orders GROUP BY customer HAVING 
COUNT(id)>=x) AS Custom_count;
```

EDIT:

```
sample data
id|   customer   | service_area
--------------------------------
 1|     c1       |   ser1
 2|     c1       |   ser1
 3|     c1       |   ser1
 4|     c1       |   ser1
 5|     c2       |   ser2
 6|     c2       |   ser2
 7|     c3       |   ser1
 8|     c3       |   ser1
```

It should look like this

```
Service area | No. of customers that placed x orders in the service area
------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |
             |
             |
```

Comment: Sample data would really help here.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. `distinct (a)` is the same as `distinct a` and `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` and the same as `distinct a,b`

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want :

```
SELECT o.service_area, COUNT(o.customer)
FROM orders o
GROUP BY o.service_area;
```

If you want unique customer count the use `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this:

```
select service_area, count(distinct customer)  customer_cnt
  from orders
 group by service_area
having count(id) > :your_variable_order_count
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT customer, COUNT(DISTINCT service_area) as num_service_area
      FROM orders
      GROUP BY customer
     ) c
WHERE num_service_area > 2;
```

That is, the subquery aggregates by `customer` and counts the number of service areas.  The outer query then counts the customers that meet the conditions you specify.

Answer (score 0):

using TSQL Server syntax:

```
declare @variable int = 1;
SELECT service_area,NoOfCust
FROM 
    (
     SELECT service_area, COUNT(id) as NoOfCust FROM orders group by service_area HAVING 
     COUNT(service_area)>= @variable
    ) AS Custom_count;
```